# How can I best resolve this error from Angular tutorial?

Tags: angular

I've been able to complete the steps on the Angular tutorial (Heroes App) fine so far, but I'm afraid i'm having issues getting past this error:
 Failed to compile.

> ./node_modules/angular-in-memory-web-api/http-backend.service.js
>   Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '@angular/http' in 'C:\Users\PholiworkX\Documents\P_WorkX\Training\angular-tour-of-heroes\node_modules\angular-in-memory-web-api'

Any help please, PS I am a beginner in coding.

Comment: try to install "npm install @angular/http" and run the app again

Answer (score 0):

If you have the "angular/http" in your package.json file, do `npm install`.

If not, `npm install -s @angular/http`.